# Curved labels with data defined coordinates in QGIS

Tags: style, qgis-3

**My goal:** I want to have curved labels placed in the center of a linestring. I define the label position with the expression x: `$x_at( num_points( $geometry)/2)` y: `$y_at( num_points( $geometry)/2)` to center the labels.

**My problem:** When I set data defined coordinates the label gets displayed horizontally even though I have set the label placement to curved (possibly due to an old [QGIS bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/6439)):[image]

**My (unsatisfactory) solution:** I also set an expression for the rotation (`angle_at_vertex( $geometry , num_points( $geometry)/2)-90`), but the results are by far not as good as having a curved label:[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to create curved labels centered on a linestring?